# Full list of index/default file names

Tags: directoryindex

I am creating a spider for one of my websites and I need a way to determine what the index file of a website is.  I understand there are a lot of different file names.  I am not worried about those who set custom filenames.  Below is a list of what I have found so far.  Does anyone have a complete list?

```
index.html
index.htm
index.shtml
index.php
index.php5
index.php4
index.php3
index.cgi
default.html
default.htm
home.html
home.htm
Index.html
Index.htm
Index.shtml
Index.php
Index.cgi
Default.html
Default.htm
Home.html
Home.htm
placeholder.html
default.asp
Default.asp
index.asp
Index.asp
```

Comment: What if the site in question doesn't use "files" like these?  Come to think of it, what sets apart an "index file" from any other URL on that site?

Comment: I am trying to reduce duplication for example  site.com = site.com/index.html most companies use a set variation of file names.  My system checks for /index.html and removes it from the system I wish to filter those out without having to do a page duplication check.